# Liquid Crystal LCD Display Prints f in all rows and columns

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, tmrpcm

The problem is that the Liquid Crystal LCD display only prints "f" on every row and every column.

When I tell it to print something, then the display prints "f" on every square(row, column) for a brief second, then each square shows three white bars stacked up parallel to each other (quite like an "=" sign except that there's one more bar on top").

I am also using a tmrpcm library, so I'm guessing that interrupts might have to do with this, but I have no idea how to solve the problem.

The link to the tmrpcm library is as follows: https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm

Thank you so much. I need to get this done by tomorrow 8 A.M., so I'm pretty desperate.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <SD.h>                      // need to include the SD library
//#define SD_ChipSelectPin 53  //example uses hardware SS pin 53 on Mega2560
#define SD_ChipSelectPin 10  //using digital pin 4 on arduino nano 328
#include <TMRpcm.h>           //  also need to include this library...

TMRpcm tmrpcm;   // create an object for use in this sketch
char mychar;
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

volatile int pauseOnOff;

void setup(){

  tmrpcm.speakerPin = 9; //11 on Mega, 9 on Uno, Nano, etc

  if (!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin)) {  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
    Serial.println("SD fail");  
    return;   // don't do anything more if not
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("success!");
  }

  tmrpcm.play("Closer.wav");

  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop(){

}
```

Comment: If the problem is “something to do with interrupts” you will need to show some code for the problem to be diagnosed.  Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code.   On the other hand, it may be a wiring problem.  In that case, edit your question to include a circuit diagram and parts list.

Comment: Thank you, but I can confirm that the wiring is not the problem by excluding the tmrpcm library and confirming that the display works correctly. Furthermore, I do not know how the tmrpcm library works...I've been studying for it for a few weeks but I still don't grasp how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the source of the problem, but here are a few things that might help diagnose where the problem begins or what it is due to.

(a) To track execution progress, and detect which statement, if any, ruins LCD operation:  Create a routine to display current line number in code to LCD and Serial; make a macro `ss` to use for invoking that routine; invoke the macro before and after each line containing a `tmrpcm` action by calls like `ss;`.  See following example.

```
void shoLine(int line) {
  Serial.println(line);
  lcd.home ();     // Set cursor to 0,0
  lcd.print(line);
  lcd.print(' ');
  delay(200);  // /Delay long enough to see stuff appear
}
#define ss shoLine(__LINE__)
```

<sup>Note:  Move `lcd.begin(16, 2);` to be the first statement in `setup()` when using this method of debugging.</sup>

(b) If you find that the first few LCD calls are ok and then LCD output stops working, try turning off interrupts during LCD output.  That is, put a `cli()` or `noInterrupts()` call before an `lcd.print()`, and an `sei()` or `interrupts()` after it, and see if it then works.  If so, that might serve as a last-ditch workaround.  (I don't know whether LCD output routines use any interrupts; I doubt they do; but if they do, this method won't work.)

(c) If the LCD doesn't display correctly at all, even before the first `tmrpcm` action, it may be that the combination of `tmrpcm` with other code is using too much memory.  Carefully check the memory-usage reports when you compile your sketch.